# Enabling ECDH in secp256k1 python?

Tags: cryptography, python-3.6, diffie-hellman

I have installed secp256k1, so that i can use ECDH functionality

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev libgmp-dev libyaml-cpp-dev
pip install secp256k1
```

on its documentation its, written that

```
NOTE: ecdh can only be used if the secp256k1 C library is compiled 
with support for it. If there is no support, an Exception will be 
raised when calling it
```

Obviously it failed because i didnt have C library installed .

I then installed

https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1 according to the documentation. 
I then uninstalled secp256k1 and installed it again.

```
pip uninstall secp256k1 
LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib pip install secp256k1 --no-binary
```

Still, i am getting the same error while trying to run ECDH. How can i make this error go away.

Comment: See https://github.com/andreacorbellini/ecc/blob/master/scripts/ecdhe.py for an excellent implementation of ECDH secp256k1 key generation and key exchange using native python without additional libraries.